# Why is my solution incorrect for tour of go slices exercise?

Tags: go

I am learning golang and trying to finish the tour of go. I am stuck on the exercise for slices. Copy pasting the question and my solution here. Can someone critique it and tell me what I am doing incorrectly here?

Question:

```
Implement Pic. It should return a slice of length dy, each element of which is a slice of dx 8-bit 
unsigned integers. When you run the program, it will display your picture,
interpreting the integers as grayscale (well, bluescale) values.

The choice of image is up to you. Interesting functions include (x+y)/2, x*y, and x^y.

(You need to use a loop to allocate each []uint8 inside the [][]uint8.)

(Use uint8(intValue) to convert between types.)
```

My Solution:

```golang
package main

import "golang.org/x/tour/pic"

func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    ans := make([][]uint8, dy)
    for i:=0; i< dy; i++ {
        slice := make([]uint8, dx)
        for j := 0; j<dx;j++{
            slice = append(slice, uint8((i+j)/2))
        }
        ans = append(ans,slice)
    }
    return ans
}

func main() {
    pic.Show(Pic)
}
```

Upon running I get the error:

> panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Also, why is there a function being passed in the exercise? Is this intended?

Comment: I don't immediately see something, that would cause index out of range. Can you tell us, in which line go panics? Also, you shouldn't use append, when you already initialized your array with the required length. Use `slice[j] = uint((i+j)/2)` and `ans[i] = slice` instead of your append calls.

Comment: Oh and yes, passing a function is used quite a lot. For example when definding AWS lambda functions.

Comment: pasting all of the output from the console below: 

`panic: runtime error: index out of range [0] with length 0

goroutine 1 [running]:
golang.org/x/tour/pic.Show(0xc0000001a0)
 /tmp/gopath4212376619/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tour@v0.0.0-20201207214521-004403599411/pic/pic.go:36 +0x153
main.main()
 /tmp/sandbox1296331084/prog.go:18 +0x25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it. As I said in my comment, you should replace your append calls by `slice[j] = uint((i+j)/2)` and `ans[i] = slice`.

The exercise calls your function with 256x256. You create a slice that is 256 long and then append other slices 256 times, resulting in a 512 long slice `ans`. The first 256 entries are empty, since append appends `slice` at the end. Therefore when the pic library iterates your data, it tries to access an empty slice.

Update:
Another way to fix the algorithm is to initialize the slices with length of 0. So editing

`ans := make([][]uint8, 0)` and
`slice := make([]uint8, 0)`

should also give the correct results.

Comment: From what I understand the problematic part is while initializing the slice I am passing a length argument. My understanding was that the length argument actually just defined the length and did not fill empty values. But seems like it does. I created a go playground link for reinforcing this [here](https://play.golang.org/p/GdJA1H4Dozz). So instead of `ans := make([][]uint8, dy)` i should have done `ans := make([][]uint8, 0)`.

Comment: Can you update your answer to explain this clearly.

Comment: Exacly @vector-hector :)

@chain_of_dogs
https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#append
`The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice. If it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the new elements. ...`

Comment: @chain_of_dogs Yes, that would work too. Hence, I updated my answer. From what I understand however, my first version would be the preferred one, because go knows how much space to allocate when you initialize it. Using append it looks to reallocate space if it runs out.